# uml class diagram relationship questions

Tags: uml

I've read a lot in internet. But still confused, may be somebody can clarify for me.

I have two questions:

1. Class `C` is a part of class `B`. If class `A` need to get class `C` through a getter in class `B` (i.e. B.getClassC()). Assume there is no other relationship between `A` and `B`. Then what should I draw in the class diagram? A-B association? or A-C association?
2. Kind of reverse case of previous one. class `B` is a part of class `A` (composition). A has association with class `C`. Now `B` is using `C` as a parameter. Then do I need to specify the relationship between `B` and `C`? And what relationship? (uses?)

Theoretically, there is a relationship between A and B in question 1, and a relationship between B and C in question 2. But if I specify all of those in class diagram, that may cause diagram more complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Getting a class is a very rare operation. Surely you mean something else. We are getting/setting values usually. Second, make difference between classes, instances, functions and attributes. Third - what do you mean by "class A is a part of class B"? Is B a parent class? Has an instance of B an attribute that is an instance of A? Is A declared as an inner class in B? Correct your question, it has no sense as is.

Comment: Composition means that class A has an attribute that consists of instances of B.

Answer (score 0):

I would not get too hung up about what exactly is the correct way to display it in UML. UML does not state that you MUST show every relationship in a diagram, that would lead to a mess.

The 'soft' relationships that you are talking about, I would just leave out of the diagram, or just display in the diagram as a dependency. Which means if something in C changes then it will/can have an effect on A.

[image]

UML is there to communicate a design. It does not say you must show everything. I would leave these 'soft' relationships out of the picture. Composition relationships (ie formed in constructor) are really the only relationships you should be concerned about. If it is not a composition relationship you want to show, have a hard think about whether or not it is communicating anything to the end user.

Comment: In so small diagrams you MUST show all relationships, or they'd be of no use at all.

Comment: it depends. I find if i want to illustrate cardinality, then i would just put those links in. uml is very flexible, and more like a sketch tool rather than an absolute 100% visual representation of the system.